# Proving a Bessel function property using trigonometrical integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I need to prove, knowing the (first order) Bessel function:

$$J_n(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(nt - x\sin(t)) \ dt$$

that the following equality is true:

$$J_{n-1}(x) + J_{n+1}(x) = \frac{2n}{x}J_n$$

After a long time trying to solve this on my own, I opened the correction book. Here is a step I can't understand:

[image: in the correction book]

I suspect an integration by parts, since the derivative factor of $\cos(nt - x\sin (t))$, which is $n-x\cos(t)$, appears.

Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: It may be more useful to use the form $$ J_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{2 \, \pi} \, \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i (n t - x \, \sin t)} \, dt $$ and consider the relation in question.

Comment: For that step: write the factor $x\cos t$ as the difference of two things:$$\big(n\big) - \big(n - x\cos t\big)$$

Comment: @Leucippus unfortunately I'm forced to use the form given by the exercice :-(

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for the tip, I'll check that

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg Ok, so show that the form given in the exercise is equal to the one given by Leucippus. It's not difficult.